# How to fetch nested component props?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a table component which has one attribute 'head'. This head expects an array value. When I pass a row component with cells, an array of div, I can access these cells and use a map function on them.
However, If I pass this row component in  wrapper component with same structure and then use this wrapper component in head, I am not able to get access of the cells.

Working code

```
head={[
        <Row
        cells={[
            <div key={0}>Head1</div>,
            <div key={1}>Head2</div>,
            <div key={2}>Head3</div>,
            <div key={3}>Head4</div>
        ]}
        />
    ]}
```

Code with wrapper component

```
const wrapper = () => <Row
                            cells={[
                                <div key={0}>Head1</div>,
                                <div key={1}>Head2</div>,
                                <div key={2}>Head3</div>,
                                <div key={3}>Head4</div>
                            ]}
                        />

head={[<wrapper />]}
```

I want to access cells array under row component even though I am using wrapper component

Comment: Untested idea: Have you tried `const wrapper = (<Row cells={...} />);` ?

Comment: This does work, I have already tried this.
But Is there any solution with wrapper being the functional component, because I cannot change the wrapper component to normal assignment